# better implementation of loading data to listview from parsed data

Tags: android

i have response for a news site which conatins more than 50 articles.so it is taking a lot of time to parse that and after parsing i am displaying it.As a result the user will be irritated .I want to display 1st 3 artivle as soon as it parse and while scrolling the list view it will fetch next 5 and show .I think in this way our response time will be reduced.plz suggest me any idea

Answer (score 0):

You should use loading listview read the given tutorial fot inplementing it the url is that.

http://androidcore.com/android-programming-tutorials/466-progressively-loading-listviews.html

I hope you have solve your problem using it.